# Target doesn't work when clicking on a link. Doesn't display content

Tags: reactjs, components, styles

[image]when you click on the picture, another picture should appear. If you replace target with hover, then everything works.
But with target it also continues to fail.

react code:

```
const Home:React.FC<any> = () =>{
  const [state = {data: []}, setState] = useState<any>({data: []})
  const getResult = async() => {
    let response:any = await sendRequest('POST','http://127.0.0.1:5500/api/home')
    setState({data: response})
  }
  useEffect(()=>{ getResult() }, [])
  const data:any = state.data.map((item:any) => {
    return (<SectionHome>
      <SectionHomeDiv id={item.id}>
        <a href={item.show_name} key={item.id} >
          <img src={item.picture_target} alt={item.show_name} key={item.id}/>
          <span><h5>{item.show_name}</h5></span>
        </a>
      </SectionHomeDiv>
      <a href={'#' + item.id} key={item.id}>
        <img src={item.pictures} alt={item.show_name} key={item.id}/>
        <span><h5>{item.show_name}</h5></span>
      </a>
    </SectionHome>) 
  })
  console.log(state)
return (<Main>
    <DivHome>
      {data}
    </DivHome>
</Main>)}
```

when clicking on a picture, a new picture on top is not displayed

style-component:

```
:target section{ // :hover - it's work 
   display: block;
   position: absolute;
   top:0;
   left: 0;
   img{
         max-width: 600px;
         height: auto;
   }
}
```

Comment: The click event is propagating to the anchor tag, your app reloads. Do you want the `img` elements to specifically handle being clicked?

Comment: yes, I need that when I click on the picture, there is a transition to the # link, and then another picture is displayed, which would lead to the page.

Comment: should work as in the picture

Comment: I'm stupid, the blockage is not the right one target